# Area of a triangle equals the area of rectangle

Tags: geometry

The area of ​​a right triangle with a base of 90m and a height of 40m is equal to the area of ​​a rectangle. What are the dimensions of the rectangle (width, height). It does not specify whether the dimensions are natural numbers or decimals. From what I understand there are many pairs of numbers that have a product of 1800.

Forgive me if the question is not well worded. Thank you for your help

Comment: As you say, there are many pairs of numbers that have a product of $1800$.  There are $18$ pairs of positive integers whose product is $1800$ (ignoring order) and infinite numbers of pairs of rational or real numbers

Comment: @Henry thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question should mention that either the solution is over integers or natural numbers or rational numbers or real number. If the solution is natural, then there are 18 pairs, you can check this by checking the factors of 1800. Other than that, if the solution is over integer or rational or any superset of integer, then there will be infinitely many pairs.

Comment: Maybe you didn’t mean “integer “ in the last sentence?

Comment: And what about Gaussian integers, which comprise a superset of integers?

Comment: Please read *thoroughly* the post [Enforcement of Quality Standards on math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1).